# Excel . Give Weight to Score between Two %

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

i need solution for Formula , if i have Score for certain name that i need to give him weight . like in below

[image]

but there is already determine score & weight that i want to select from it

[image]

above is can be done if Target Score is = to Actual Score but almost it inst 
so i need to give weight for the actual score if he between Two target score 
like if he got 93 % so he will be in target score from ( 92% to 94 %) so i need to give him weight % from ( 0% to 4 % )

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your lookup table to be sorted in ascending order and add a row of a score of 0%:

[image]

2. Use the following formula:

   ```
   =INDEX(H$2:H$6,MATCH(B2,G$2:G$6,1))
   ```

[image]
(adjust cells to match your file)